# Empty URL In SiteMapNode

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I've got a SiteMap with blank URL attributes in each siteMapNode.  Anyone know how to render them if the URL is blank?  I'm doing a foreach against the SiteMap.CurrentNode and it doesn't retrieve siteMapNode elements that have empty URL attributes, but I do need to render them (just without a URL).

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not know it's good or bad practice. But generally for such requirement I do use string "#" as empty url. It serves empty url purpose.

Comment: How it will work? if you use # as a url that will works for only one time. If you want to you multiple times then how?

Comment: If you have only one instance where `url="#"` then you're in good shape. If you have more than one of them in your sitemap, you're in trouble because it breaks a fundamental rule of the sitemap. You can't have more than one of the same URL in a sitemap.

Answer (score 6):

To render a site map node with a blank URL, simply remove the URL attribute altogether from the node. It will then render, but not be clickable (if you are using security trimming, include the roles attribute, e.g. roles="*" or e.g. roles="Admin" since there is no URL to authorize against.)

Comment: Jacob, that is incorrect. Removing the url attribute from the node does not make the node unclickable, rather it brings up the directory listing for the application as a result.