# menu item not visible, when url attribute of sitemapnode is empty

Tags: asp.net

Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941269/empty-url-in-sitemapnode)
But it doesn't provide any solution.  The accepted answer for this question only works for one menu item.  If we use "#" as a url for multiple items then it will give error like `same url # was used multiple times`. Thats why I again posted this to hear solution from experts. My question is,

I have sitemap like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode title="Invisible" description="Main Page" url="Menu.aspx" >
    <siteMapNode title="Home" url="Default.aspx" />
    <siteMapNode  title="Time Sheets" url="#">
      <siteMapNode title="Time Sheet Entry" description="Menu one" url="Menu1.aspx" />
      <siteMapNode title="Time Sheet Approval" description="Menu Two" url="Menu2.aspx" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode title="Leaves">
      <siteMapNode title="Leave Request" url="leaverequest.aspx" />
      <siteMapNode title="Leave Approval" url="leaveapproval.aspx"/>
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode roles="Administrator" description="Only for administrators" title="Reports" url="SubMenu1.aspx" />
    <siteMapNode  title="Administration" url="~/UserRegistration.aspx"  >
      <siteMapNode  title="Register New User" url="~/Account/AdminRegister.aspx"></siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode title="Help" url="~/Account/UserSettings.aspx" description=""></siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

For leaves node there is no any url. Under the leaves there are two submenus. These only contains urls to a specific page. But when i render this in my master page, the `Leaves` node not at all appearing. I tried with empty url attribute like
`<siteMapNode title="Leaves" url="#">`. This also doesn't provide me the solution. What would be the mistake in my sitemap page?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution that I did for this exact scenario was to put "#" on the first URL, then "##" on the second, "###" on the third and so on. This makes the links non-clickable and also satisfies the unique url rule.  Hack? maybe, but works for what I'm using it for.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but if you define the roles attribute as non-empty, eg.

```
<siteMapNode url="" title="Leaves" roles="*">
```

Then the node **is** rendered.  Unfortunately, I do not know why.  Hope this helps someone!